# Getting Facebook userid from profile urls listed in a notepad file

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I have seen a lot of websites/scripts that retrieves facebook UID from profile url. (lookup-id.com, findmyfbid.com etc). My question is that, if I have multiple profile IDs (url) listed in a notepad file, is it possible to get UIDs of all the url by running a loop with a program or a Script?

I have searched this and few other websites but did not get a relevant information or a code that can be manipulated a bit to fulfill my requirement.

Appreciate some help here.

Thanks

Comment: use `fopen` to read the text file and then get the fb id from your code.

Comment: It is not possible any more to look up users by their username, Facebook has deliberately removed the `username` field with APi v2.0.

Comment: but lookup-id.com and findmyfbid.com works!  I guess the field name must be uid or some other name. I dont need the username, I need the numeric ID of the user. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) to fetch the urls from the text file, like:

```
<?php

$fh = fopen('file_name.txt','r');
while ($line = fgets($fh)) {
  // echo($line);
  // your code to fetch facebook id
}
fclose($fh);

?>
```

or, by using [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
<?php
$array = explode("\n", file_get_contents('file_name.txt'));
//this will return you an array, loop through the array and your code to get fb id
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to look out for a code to fetch facebook ID. Do let me know if you have a resource where I can look out for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the numbers only:

```
<?php
$line = explode("\n", file_get_contents('file_name.txt'));

foreach($line as $string){

   $id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $string); //remove all non-numeric characters

   //if empty, nothing :)
   if(!$id){  
   }

   //otherwise, print result with linebreak
   else{
   echo $id."<br/>"; //only result is numbers
   }

}
```

In this case, `file_name.txt` has these rows:

```
facebook.com/1
facebook.com/2
facebook.com/3
facebook.com/4
http://www.facebook.com/5
www.facebook.com/6
```

Output would now be:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: Thank you. I am assuming that I need to add a code in the section if(!$id){     } Right? I am not good in that but will search how to get uid for a single url. If you have any resource, do let me know. Thank you.

Comment: no, add your code in the else{ codehere } statement, as the IF only filter out empty ones

Comment: I am not getting this right. The txt file will have something like facebook.com/tom, facebook.com/dick, facebook.com/harry and so on... I need to output their facebook user ids like how lookup-id.com website works.